# How do I redirect a single url for a specific server block in an nginx config

Tags: nginx, redirect

In an nginx server block:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name foo.com bar.com car.com;

  ...
 }
```

How do I redirect `bar.com/site` and only `bar.com/site` to `bar.com/` - the other hosts should remain unaffected. So `foo.com/site` and `car.com/site` should work as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($host ~* ^bar.com$) {
    rewrite ^/site(.*)$ /;
}
```

or different server locations with include of shared zones

Comment: I like "different server locations with include of shared zones" better. Nginx docs say [if is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) and recommend avoiding it when possible. (But rewrite *is* one of the directives they say is safe inside `if` blocks, so this answer is perfectly correct.)

Comment: So obvious! Thanks :) I've just added a `permanent` so its a redirect rather than a rewrite.

Comment: Yep, if its evil. Check all requests not the best practice for high-load servers. More faster - takes 3 servers like: server {server_name foo.com; include someconf.conf;}

Comment: Yep, well aware of the "if is evil" :)